# C# TDD Testing an array[int] not working as expected

Tags: c#, unit-testing, tdd

I'm trying to create a test for a method that is passed an int[] array of AllNumbers and returns an int[] array of only EvenNumbers.  Although debugging the test shows me that the `Expected` and `Actual` are the same the test still fails.  I'm guessing it's a `.Equals` versus `==` problem?

Error:

```
Failed  TestEvenNumbers CalculatorEngineTests   Assert.AreEqual failed. Expected:<System.Int32[]>. Actual:<System.Int32[]>.
```

This is my test:

```
[TestMethod]
    public void TestEvenNumbers()
    {
        Calculator target = new Calculator();
        int[] test = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };
        int[] expected = { 2, 4, 6, 8 };
        int[] actual = target.GetEvenNumbers(test);

        //This passes
        Assert.AreEqual(expected[1], actual[1]);
        //This fails
        Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
    }
```

This is the method I want to test:

```
public int[] GetEvenNumbers(int[] arr)
    {
        var evenNums =
            from num in arr
            where num % 2 == 0
            select num;


        return evenNums.ToArray<int>();
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
CollectionAssert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
```

To assert that the collections contain the same things, as I believe the Assert.AreEqual will simply compare the references.

Comment: Thank you for the help.   :)